# Is it generally safe (and compliant) to log a stack trace?

Tags: pci-dss, logging, sensitive-data-exposure

I work on financial web sites that maintain PCI-DSS, FDIC/FFIEC, and ISO-27000 compliance.  Also, we are big fans of OWASP :)

Our web sites log errors in cleartext to a flat file held on the web server.  These sites handle a lot of high value PII.

I am wondering is it generally safe, and compliant, and I shouldn't give it a second thought, to log the stack trace when an exception is thrown?  Are there any questions I should ask myself before including it?  Or is this a no-brainer?

Comment: If you have some.data-dependent branching, I can see some minor leakage of PII. For example: `Java.lang.RuntimeException at checkIsBuyingPorn:300 at handleSocialSecurityNumberStartsWithFive:250 at doPost:180`.

Answer (score 1):

Stacktraces would be really valuable for the developers in order to understand bugs in your application (Or for administrator in case of being attacked), but you shouldn't be loging sensitive information like usernames, passwords or any similar information. That's cause if you do and your logs fall in bad hands, the harm could be much worse than some attacker being able to understand a few bugs

Also, logs should be stored in a different partition than your webserver, that's to avoid a possible DoS. Under certain attacks your log files will increase drastically which may fill the webserver partition and prevent it from working. A good backup policy to prevent this is encouraged too